# how to join multiple tables and extract certain column on SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Here are the tables

Customer (Id, Name, Address, City, State, Zip)
Account (Id, CustomerID, OpenDate, CloseDate, Type, Balance)
Transaction (Id, AccountId, Amount, BranchId...)
Branch (Id, Name, Address, City, State, Zip)

And the question goes: **List the names of the customers who made transactions of an amount exceeding $100 any bank branch in Seattle.**

I am thinking about something like this, but I am not sure how to do the rest from here:
SELECT Name
FROM Customer c
JOIN Account a ON a.CustomerID = c.Id
JOIN

Please help, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Name FROM Customer c INNER JOIN Account a ON c.Id = a.CustomerID INNER JOIN TRANSACTION t on t.AccountId = a.Id INNER JOIN BRANCH b ON t.BranchID = b.Id WHERE t.AMOUNT > 100 AND t.branch = "Seattle"
```